# what would path for a class in filter of web.xml of tomcat if class is in jar file of WEB-INF/lib

Tags: tomcat, servlets, servlet-filters

I have created a filter class which is in a jar in WEB-INF/lib of my application. Now I need to map   in web.xml of Tomcat/conf
to that class file.

I thought tomcat exposes all class files in WEB-INF/lib so that classes are available directly.

Apache's deployment guide quotes

> When you install an application into Tomcat (or any other 2.2 or later
>   Servlet container), the classes in the WEB-INF/classes/ directory, as
>   well as all classes in JAR files found in the WEB-INF/lib/ directory,
>   are made visible to other classes within your particular web
>   application. Thus, if you include all of the required library classes
>   in one of these places (be sure to check licenses for redistribution
>   rights for any third party libraries you utilize), you will simplify
>   the installation of your web application -- no adjustment to the
>   system class path (or installation of global library files in your
>   server) will be necessary.

I have given path in filter as 
com.(company_name).(package_name).class_name

but tomcat is not picking it up.
Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: My mistake. Ill rectify it.

Comment: Can you kindly explain what do mean by go in Server? I specifically need it to map to WAR. is that possible>

Comment: You see, it is a filter class which needs to add response headers to each page of application. Thats in WAR.

Comment: I did that. but /WEB-INF/web.xml wasn't adding response headers to all pages(specifically static html pages which were coming through href) so resolved to tomcats web.xml

Answer (score 0):

As @BalusC mentioned in comments it is not possible to map to your application's WEB-INF/lib from tomcat's web.xml (tomcat/conf/web.xml).

Solution would be to put that filter class in a separate jar and place it in tomcat's lib (tomcat/lib). Currently that seems to be the only solution possible.